# Raspberry pi as a cell phone for calling

Tags: raspbian, gsm

I am building a device for car security and i am using raspberry pi 4. I want to establish a connection between the people inside the car and the outside. I want to make calls from mobile to raspberry pi. Is it possible? And if yes then how?

Comment: Hi @Shaji Ul Haq, hobbyists used to play with SIM800/900, or SIM7600. I would recommend 4G LTE SIM7600. Reference: (1) "AliExpress SIM7600 Catalog":
https://fr.aliexpress.com/af/sim7600.html?d=y&origin=n&SearchText=sim7600. You might like to search this forum for "SIM800", "SIM900", "SIM7600", "LTE"

Comment: this may give you some ideas ... https://www.instructables.com/id/ArduinoPhone/